# DownloadFile without full path

Tags: c#, webclient

I am making a WindowsForm application and want to **download a file** (xls) from a webpage. The file is generated on clicking an image on that webpage and gives me SaveAs dialogue.
Now, the URL dosen't give full path of the file and using some NetworkSniffing tools I found that the file download URL is same as the webpage URL.

I am using the below code but the problem is it downloads the entire webpage instead of the file.

URL is (as) : http://rambo.xxx.com/ADHOC/UserReports.aspx?ADHOC_ID=63

I am using this code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile(@"http://rambo.xxx.com/ADHOC/UserReports.aspx?ADHOC_ID=63", @"C:\temp.xls");
    }
```

I know it is dynamically generated by some .aspx file but is there no way at all to download the file programmatically?

Searched SO & Google but didn't get my question answered.

Edit: [Link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05660612172330845855) to the ViewSource of the Page added.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I meant, the URL dosent give full path of that file. Like : "http://www.example.com/file/test.xls"

Comment: It can't be the same as the web page URL. Try use Fiddler2.

Comment: Is this the real URL? Not Found
The requested URL /ADHOC/UserReports.aspx was not found on this server.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan : Downloading Filder right now. Will let you know.

Comment: It's also possible that the page contains Javascript that does does the actual download. Have you examined the source of the page to see what's in there?

Comment: @JimMischel I can see some javascripts in it but unfortunately I have no knowledge of web apps. Is there a way of calling / clicking that image to generate the file via C# ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: I downloaded Fiddler. URL of file is the same

Comment: Does the button posts a form to the page? You should then try to emulate the POST, currently you are executing a GET request.

Comment: "Is there a way of calling / clicking that image to generate the file via C#?" I don't know. Probably. Depends on the Web page and whether you'll need a Javascript interpreter to read and process the page. I can't say without looking at the actual page. The results from Fiddler should help you.

Comment: @JimMischel : Link to ViewSource: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05660612172330845855

Comment: It is impossible that the two DIFFERENT resources have the same Uniform Resource Locator

Comment: @HamletHakobyan : I have included the ViewSource. Will this help?